# can i change my font on a click in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, font-family

I am using Vuejs with vuetify components i have customize my website to have two languages with   Internationalization (i18n).
the problem is i also want to change my font when i change to my second language bur don't know how to do that.

```
style
.font{
        font-family: 'b nazanin'; 
 /*i want to use this font after i change my language*/
    }

<template>
<button  v-for="entry in languages" :key="entry.title" @click="changeLocale(entry.language)"v-on:click="font">
                    <flag :iso="entry.flag" ></flag>
                    {{entry.title}}
                </button>


<h1  v-bind:style="{font}">{{ $t('titleInHome') }}</h1>
</template>
```

can anyone please help me in this case thank you all

Comment: :style="(entry.language == 'special_font_language') ? 'font-family:b nazanin' : ''"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with style binding.

**HTML Template:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1 :style="styles">Apply font here</h1> <br>
      <button  v-for="entry in langs" @click="changeFont(entry.title)" :key="entry.title">
        {{ entry.title }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script:**

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    styleObj:{
      color :'blue',
      border: '2px blue dotted',
      backgroundColor:'gray',
      fontFamily:'Time New Roman'
    },
    langs:[
      { title :'Vue.js'},
      { title:'React'},
      { title:'Angular'}
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    changeFont(lang){
      let fontFamily = null; 
      if(lang == "Vue.js"){
         fontFamily = "Arial";
       }
      else if(lang == "React"){
        fontFamily = "Verdana";
      }
      else{
        fontFamily = "Calibri";
      }
      this.styleObj.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    }
  }
});
```

[Complete Example](https://codepen.io/tech-49/pen/mdywbMP)

Comment: thank you so much for your help and can i :style="styles" in other components too ?

Comment: It's a "Data" property so this limited to the current component/instance only. If you want to use `styles` in multiple components then you can create Mixins. Mixins is a feature in Vue.js to define commons things globally.

If you don't know how to do it with Mixins let me know I will show you.

Comment: i have created a lanmixins,js file that includes my methods and my data and i have imported it in my components and added it like  mixins: [lanmixins] so now i thought i could use :style="styles" for my other tags too but it seems i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic style or a dynamic class, these can depend on some variable inside your code. See here for example:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

For example you could write two classes and then something like this:

```
:class="{'classOne': languageA: ,  'classTwo': languageB}" //(languageA and B would be bools in this case)
```